# Cross Browser, Javascript-less, Skip Navigation Link

Tags: html, cross-browser, accessibility

In a recent search on best practices for Skip Navigation links, this is the most comprehensive solution I could find: http://www.communis.co.uk/blog/2009-06-02-skip-links-chrome-safari-and-added-wai-aria

What I don't like about this one is that it requires JavaScript on Webkit browsers. Is this really the best solution we have for something seemingly as simple as a skip navigation link?

Have any links or samples that talk about other, "better" solutions?

Answer (score 2):

A good skip link should be alway visible to alert user's to its presence. A good alternative is to use CSS to make the skip link visible when it receives the focus.

Consider this HTML

```
<div id="skip"><a href="#content">Skip to content</a></div>
```

Used with this CSS

```
#skip a {
position: absolute;
margin-left: -3000px;
width: 1;
height: 1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
#skip a:focus, #skip a:active {
margin-left: 0px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

The link is hidden until it receives the focus. `:focus` caters for non IE browsers, and `:active` caters for IE users. A mouse user will never see the link, as there is no `:hover` used.

update: 03\02\11
Links to some useful articles on skip link implementation and usability

- http://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200909/skip_links_need_to_be_at_least_temporarily_visible/
- http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/accessibility/nice-css-skip-links-appearing-focus/

Comment: This is similar to the approach I currently use. But it is completely broken in all Webkit based browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use

```
#skip-to-nav, #skip-to-content
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}
```

And I make sure that the #skip-to-nav and #skip-to-content links are in the `body` element.

Drupal 7 uses:

```
/**
 * Hide elements visually, but keep them available for screen-readers.
 *
 * Used for information required for screen-reader users to understand and use
 * the site where visual display is undesirable. Information provided in this
 * manner should be kept concise, to avoid unnecessary burden on the user.
 * "!important" is used to prevent unintentional overrides.
 */
.element-invisible {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

/**
 * The .element-focusable class extends the .element-invisible class to allow
 * the element to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard.
 */
.element-invisible.element-focusable:active,
.element-invisible.element-focusable:focus {
  position: static !important;
  clip: auto;
}
```

I have tested both with screen readers, and they both seem to work fine for anyone who can't see the screen.

As far as tabbing order goes, I don't worry about a user tabbing to an element they can't see. I probably should, but I find that the vast majority of users don't use the tab key anyway. The ones who do tend to understand more about what's going on anyway, so IMHO it becomes moot.

Edit to add:

After some discussion with @discojoe, I decided I'd look a little closer into what drupal 7 uses for hiding/revealing content, I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Note that sighted keyboard users will also make use of skip links, and not just screenreader users, so it is good practise to make skip links visible, at least on focus. (In fact, screenreader users have shortcut keys to jump to many elements on the page, so are often less likely to use skip links than sighted keyboard users)

Comment: In most cases, skip links interrupt the visual flow of a webpage's design. Also, if your content is so far down the page that a sighted user needs a skip link, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: It's not the distance that a sighted user has to go, but how many navigation links a sighted keyboard only user would have to tab through. Consider a site with 50 nav links in the main nav bar - not unreasonable for a big site - a keyboard user would need to tab through them on every page visit. A skip link is for bypassing blocks of repeated content, not for jumping down the page.

Comment: I was under the impression that there were specialized mice for sighted users with disabilities. Eye-trackers, joysticks and the like. If your concern is the number of links a keyboard user would have to tab through, then you should put the nav *after* the content: header, content, nav, footer. The nav can then be visually positioned above the content, despite it coming *after* the content in the tabbing order.

Comment: The same logic applies; if a user wants to jump to the navigation, they then have to tab through all of the content links, in which a "skip to navigation" link can be provided. Not all users can use mice, regardless of how specialised they are. Further, there is a requirement for links to bypass block as set out in the W3C web content accessibility guidelines : See http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-skip.html for more information.

Comment: @discojoe, Very good link, I'll need to read WCAG more thoroughly. I was about to argue that adding functionality for a very small subset of users just to make the website marginally more convenient seems a bit excessive...but then I read, "...[keyboard users] might have to make dozens of keystrokes before reaching a link in the main content area. This can take a long time and may cause **severe physical pain** for some users." which makes a world of difference. Convenience for convenience sake is not a particular concern, but convenience to avoid *pain* is something I definitely agree with.

Comment: Drupal's implementation is broken. Go to http://drupal.org with any Webkit browser (Google Chrome for example). Pressing the "Tab" key makes the link appeared as expected. Pressing the "Enter" key makes the page scroll down to the main content, as expected. But, pressing "Tab" again jumps the focus back to the top of the page, thus making the tabbing functionality a moot point. Most Skip Nav implementations I have seen have this same issue.